# conditional replacement with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace, offset

I'm new to python and pandas...

I have a data frame with one text column. I would like,for the entire column, to replace the value "AZB" with the value above that value (an offset of -1)

How can I achive that? I tried with pandas "where" and also tried

```
df[(df['INDEX'] == 'AZB')] = df['INDEX']-1
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `'AZB'` values to `NaN`, and then use `fillna(method='ffill')` to replace them with the values from the row above.

```
df.ix[df['INDEX'] == 'AZB', 'INDEX'] = np.NaN
df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

If your data set isn't huge, another way would be to iterate through your dataframe row by row, but it would be much slower:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df.ix[i, 'INDEX'] == 'AZB':
        df.ix[i, 'INDEX'] = df.ix[i-1, 'INDEX']
```